# use of restorePreviousSignIn() in googleSign in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

Google migration doc [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/quick-migration-guide) says that

```swift
// Old:
guard let signIn = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance() else { return }
if (signIn.hasAuthInKeychain()) {
  signIn.signInSilently()
}

// New:
guard let signIn = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance() else { return }
if (signIn.hasPreviousSignIn()) {
  signIn.restorePreviousSignIn()

  // If you ever changed the client ID you use for Google Sign-in, or
  // requested a different set of scopes, then also confirm that they
  // have the values you expect before proceeding.
  if (signIn.currentUser.authentication.clientID != YOUR_CLIENT_ID
      // TODO: Implement hasYourRequiredScopes
      || !hasYourRequiredScopes(signIn.currentUser.grantedScopes)) {
    signIn.signOut()
  }
}
```

As I had tried with device user still get redirect to account.google.com and have to choose the account right? so what is use of restorePreviousSignIn(). How it benefit to user? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you **set** the `GIDSignInDelegate` (`GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate`) before calling `restorePreviousSignIn()`?

As the documentation of `restorePreviousSignIn()` says:
*The delegate will be called at the end of this process indicating success or failure. The current values of `GIDSignIn`'s configuration properties will not impact the restored user.*

Btw. I'm using the restorePreviousSignIn() without any trouble.

// Sorry for asking in answer, I don't have enough reputation to comment on you question.

Comment: Yes delegate is set. what i mean to ask is how it make diff for user.

Comment: User doesn't have to relogin each time he opens your app (after app was forced closed / terminated etc.).

Comment: but it don't ask for relogin even if you don't use restorePreviousSignIn() right ?

Comment: To make it clear: You don't have to call `restorePreviousSignIn()` on app startup. But you won't be able to retreive (previously logged-in) user information from _GIDSignIn Framework_ (like `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser`). So if you need to retrieve the information about user from _GIDSignIn Framework_, you have two options: 1) Call `restorePreviousSignIn()` and wait for the delegate method beeing called. 2) Ask user to re-login (user won't be happy). Is it clear now?

Comment: but what happens if user wants to change email ?

Comment: is it became problem for that

Comment: What do you mean by _changing email_? To login with different Google Account? It's not a problem, you just need to *logout* the user first, so the LOGOUT button (that calls `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()`) should be placed somewhere in your app.

Comment: we don't have signout button in our app sadly

Comment: ok. But do you uderstand that you can _logout_ user by calling `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()`? Than you can ask user to _login_ with different account. Do you have any more question?

Comment: Yes I got your point but because I don't have logout button in app so I think that is the case I asking for

Comment: @Mickey16 How do you wait for the delegate to be called